# Chip-Seq data description

Tags: chip-seq

I have the following Chip-Seq data and could not found a description of it. Can you help me with it? More, I would like to find out the order of the nucleotides in binding regions; that is, what number they are.

```
@GWZHISEQ01:319:HA1NPADXX:1:1101:1182:2196 1:N:0:ACTGAT
GGAGGAAGTGTGTTGCTGCAGACAGTAGCAACCAGACCCACACTGCGCGTA
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHIJJJJIJJIIIIHGJJJJJJJCGHIJJIJJFHIIJJII
@GWZHISEQ01:319:HA1NPADXX:1:1101:1272:2109 1:N:0:ACTGAT
NCCACGCTAGGCTCAGCTTGTCGGCCTGGCTAAGCAGTTGCGAAAGTGCGC
+
#1=DDDFFHHHHHJJIJJJJJJIGEHGGJIGHJFHGJIJJJJJJJ@CHCBG
@GWZHISEQ01:319:HA1NPADXX:1:1101:1418:2141 1:N:0:ACTGAT
GCACGCACTACCCAGAGATCATCCAAAGCCTGAAGCCACAGGGCGCACTCG
+
CCCFFFFFGHGHHJJJIIJJJJIIHGGGIJIIJJIIIJJJIJJJIJIJIJH
@GWZHISEQ01:319:HA1NPADXX:1:1101:1302:2160 1:N:0:ACTGAT
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTG
+
CCCFFFFFHDHHHJJJJIJJJJIIIIIJIHJIJJJIIJHIIJJJJJJJJHH
```

Comment: Cross-posted [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/265387/)

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: It's frowned upon at the very least.

Comment: I would argue that cross-posting is not a problem provided you reference the cross-posts on each site.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [fastq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) file, you will want to align it to the genome, call peaks, and then use something like [MEME](http://meme-suite.org/index.html) to determine binding motifs.

Comment: how do I align it to the genome?

Comment: @frosh You need more help than a Q&A site can offer. I recommend that you attend a workshop on NGS data analysis, or find a collaborator who can do the analysis for you.

Comment: You're right. I will delete the question.

Comment: You don't need to delete it.

Comment: The following mini-courses may be useful: http://rafalab.github.io/pages/harvardx.html